# My typeorm migration:run get done but dont create the tables

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, typeorm

im working on a project that i used the mongodb, so i started the database and used the docker, every configuration are ok, but whe i put the command "yarn typeorm migration:run" it get done, but dont create the tables with all the migrations in my project, anyone can help me with this?

my ormconfig looks like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tw1Gw.png)

that's how the console become when i use the comm
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ8YX.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to migrate when you use mongdb with typeorm.Just define models, it will automatically create database table schemes based on your models.

Answer (score 0):

Add synchronize: true,
to your ormconfig and it will auto-create all tables from your entities on connection.